# how to click on a particular cell in selenium web table having dynamic id

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

Web Table will look like -

I would like to click on Edit button for Steve Smith .

```
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <td>Steve</td>
    <td>Smith</td> 
    <td>Edit</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Mark</td>
    <td>Jackson</td> 
    <td>Edit </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

What should be the approach for such scenerios?

Comment: please post the "real" html-code!

Comment: So what have you tried? What isn't working?

Comment: I tried to find out dynamic of Organization_123.Then I have stored dynamic id by get_attribute method.Then same id I have replaced with edit button.                         span_id=driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[contains(.,'Test_organization_21')]").get_attribute("id")
edit_spanid=span_id.replace("_LabelName","_LinkButtonEdit")
print edit_spanid

Answer (score 0):

I am making some assumptions here.

1. The `first name` and `last name` is known (eg: Steve Smith)
2. You can identify the target `table` without any issues.

You can use the following XPath. This Xpath will find the `tr` which has text `Steve Smith` and then navigate to the `td` containing `Edit`.

```
//tr[./td[.='Steve']][./td[.='Smith']]/td[.='Edit']
```

All this is based on the HTML you posted. Hope this helps you.

Comment: thanks for your solution. Lets assume that Edit button is present in first column .Name Steve in second column ,then how to select edit with respect to Steve ?

Comment: The xpath is cot concerned about the position of `td` tags. It simply looks for the text contained in the `td` tags.